# ERPNext issue installing Education Module

Tags: erp, modulenotfounderror, erpnext

I am trying to install education and different modules in erpnext version 14 but after installation getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Inwt.png)

i have tried
bench get-app app_name
and then
bench --site site_name install-app app_name